# How to find the right token to use in a rule for sending an email to the node author?

Tags: 7, rules

I am having the toughest time figuring out how to send an email to the node author. I created my rule and everything works if I hard code the email but I can't seem to get the right token to use and it seems the tokens available only allow:**[node:author**] nothing for the node authors email?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes, the Rules module user interface doesn't show all the allowed tokens.
Manually enter *[node:author:mail]*. If it's not an allowed token, an error message would be shown.

Comment: Great! I do confirm this tag works.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module is great, but it also has its hidden features ... ***Yes*** the "*token for the eMail Id of the node author*" is available to use it in the Rules Action. However you won't find it by simply expanding the typical "**`REPLACEMENT PATTERNS`**"-link that show up by default.

Moreover, there is no need for *guessing* or *trial-and-error* (similar to the "*So try just manually inputting [node:author:mail]` and see if it validates in Rules*" in the accepted answer). Instead, whenever you're looking for some token that at first doesn't seem to be available, you should try to use the <kbd>Switch to data selection</kbd> button as in this screenprint:

[image]

Then select "`node...(Created content)`" from the **Data selector** selection list (or if you know part of what you're looking for just start typing "`node:`"). Here is another screenprint that should look pretty similar:

[image]

After completing such selection, the list of possible values (= tokens starting with "`node:`") will change and start to show (dozens of) other values such as:

- `node:nid (Node ID)`
- `node:type (Content Type)`
- `node:author... (Node Author)`
- `node:comment (Comments allowed)`
- `node:comments... (Comments)`

In the above list, note the ones that have a "`...`": those are the ones that, after you select any of them, will bring up yet another list of tokens that start with what you selected. So if you select "`node:author... (Node Author)`", it'll show (many) other values (some with yet another "`...`"), such as:

- `node:author:uid (User ID)`
- `node:author:name (Name)`
- `node:author:mail (Email)`
- `node:author:roles... (User roles)`

So there you are: using the drill-down approach as shown above, `node:author:mail (Email)` is what you're looking for. All that's needed now, is to select it from this list. Though in this case there is no more *Label* and *Description* for the token, you only have what's shown between "`(`" and "`)`" to decide about which token to select.

PS: If you don't find what you're looking for (after using the <kbd>Switch to data selection</kbd> button), you can always return to the previous display by using the <kbd>Switch to the direct input mode</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the user is logged in when creating the node so:

```
<?
global $user;
echo $user->mail;
?>
```

Should work too.